# How to implement a simple primary key on an id field in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, sql-insert

I've been digging through stackover flow and it seems odd that a powerful database management software such as postgres does not have a simple way to provide this.

The best solution I have so far is

`id serial primary key,`,

but in the event that you want to do an

`INSERT VALUE ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`

(I'm adding this last part b/c postgres cannot do `INSERT OR IGNORE`), the sequence will count on even after insertions failed.

So The table you get might look something like:

```
id | name
1 | amy
5 | bob
12 | john
104 | thomas
```

where the in between indexes were failed insertions. The app works, but I find this annoying. Suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion?  Get used to it.  There is no problem with a `serial` primary key having gaps.  Incidentally, this behavior is true of all databases that have such functionality.  It would be very expensive (performance-wise) to remove those gaps.

Comment: The **only** responsibility of a primary key column is to uniquely identify a row. The actual value is meaningless. `-4635` is as good a primary key value as `42` or `107` or anything else that is unique in that table

Comment: Get used to the speed this provides and learn to not be annoyed with performance improvements.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sqlite has `insert or ignore`, is that expensive? forgive me for not up to your speed.

Comment: @user2167582 . . . If you rollback a transaction after the sequence has been added you are going to get gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on @Gordon Linoff 's comment, this behaviour is a vital part of scalability by allowing the DB to process inserts concurrently across connections.

Without it, to achieve the no gap scenario, every transaction would have to complete or fail in its entirety before the next ID could be assigned to any table.  DBs that use the concept of a `SEQUENCE` would not be able to cache blocks of values, meaning every allocation of a sequence number (for whatever reason) would require a lock which in turn could block.

In both cases, in order to guarantee the next value, the DB cannot proceed until nothing else is pending.  You'd basically end up with a giant queue of serialised inserts and they database would not scale, at least for inserts.

All databases work like this and this is the reason why.  I hope that helps you understand, even if you still find it annoying.  The only real way around it is to allocate a true sequence number after the event in a big batch or as you `SELECT` but you'll generally find out it's rarely if ever worth doing.

Comment: Right. You can do it, but it performs terribly, and it's not worth doing unless there's a compelling business need.

Comment: I don't even know if you can do it.  The standard DB tools like sequences and identity columns are all built to be concurrent and therefore with gaps.  `SELECT MAX(id)` doesn't work unless you somehow lock the table and even then Postgresql, like many databases, will read the last known version and carry on so you'd have the same problem.  If you could, it would be a case of working really hard to make it do something you don't want to happen.

Comment: Sure you can, google "gapless sequence postgres". You use a counter table that you `UPDATE ... SET id_counter = id_counter + 1 RETURNING id_counter` in a subquery or function you substitute for `nextval`.

Comment: @CraigRinger is right. One kind of compelling business need for gapless sequences is in accounting: check numbers, invoice numbers, and probably some other things I can't think of at the moment.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Definitely, there are appropriate uses. I kinda wish PostgreSQL had a canned helper for that. But people would inevitably just use it when they shouldn't then get confused by the resulting deadlocks and terrible performance, so making people implement it themselves isn't all bad.